# Yosemite Installation Error while Extracting Files

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I'm getting this error:

> **OS X could not be installed on your computer**
>
> An error occurred while extracting files from the package "Essentials.pkg".
>
> Quit the installer to restart your computer and try again.

Every time I restart, it installs until "19 minutes" are left and gives me the exact same error. I have no idea what to do because apparently no one else is having this problem.

[image: Installation Error]

Comment: I have the same issue: Macbook pro with Corsair SSD and a seconds HDD. I have even formated the SSD and tried clean and still no go. I know the USB drive I created is good because I used it to upgrade another machine with it. Let me clarify- all machines are supported- macbook pro 2011 and 2012

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading as it may be corrupted? And have you made sure there is enough space on the drive after the download plus extra for extraction?

Comment: I definitely have enough space (844 GB free). At the time, I couldn't redownload because all it would do is restart. However, I have just restored a backup from Time Machine and am starting over. Hopefully it isn't corrupted this time.

Comment: Try restarting your Mac while holding down "alt" of the drives that show up choose the recovery one. Once you did this you should be able to reinstall using a fresh download. I had the same error. However I'm still stuck with the installation.

Comment: I was running into this same issue. In order to complete the install, I had to open Terminal and remove a hidden directory from the root of the drive I was installing to. I don't remember the name of the directory, but by the naming it appeared to be a staging directory for the install and was listed right next to .OSInstallerMessages. I ran an rm -rf on that directory, restarted, and went through the installer as normal. Be very careful as rm -rf on the wrong directory could be catastrophic!