# Error installing Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) on a 512GB SSD in my 2010 MacBook

Tags: macbook, osx-yosemite

The Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) installer fails to extract any files onto my drive:

> **OS X could not be installed on your computer**
>
> An error occurred while extracting files from the package "Essentials.pkg".
>
> Quit the installer to restart your computer and try again.

However, I have reinstalled Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) just fine, which leads me to believe there’s something wonky going on with the installer.

Judging by the comments on [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/827880/yosemite-installation-error-while-extracting-files?noredirect=1), it seems like this error might be occurring with people who have installed SSDs in their old MacBooks. I have a mid-2010 MacBook with a 512GB SSD in the main hard drive slot and a secondary 250GB HDD in the DVD drive bay. I also have installed 16GB of RAM in this laptop. So far all of the new hardware has worked fine for the past 6 months so I doubt my issues are due to faulty hardware. I am trying to perform the install on a freshly formatted partition.

Here is the [install log](http://pastebin.com/411YT3st).

Here’s [another install log](http://pastebin.com/5rK7SKDf) from when I was trying to upgrade the OS instead of using a freshly formatted partition.

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate, but I have provided much more information (specifically specs and an install log) that the other question did not. My form of participation is to ask a question that I believe has more information that could lead to an actual answer, which the other question does not have.

Comment: Ok, since the OP in the other questions said that they reinstalled and anyway cannot reproduce the issue, I reversed the duplicate direction.

Comment: Left-field question - do you have TRIM enabled on the SSD? [logical next question... if so, what happens if you disable it first?]

Comment: Any updates @azerend?

Answer (score 2):

Trim kext is altered in Yosemite. This is not relevant if you're using an Apple installed SSD. If you're using a DIY SSD, Trim support is tricky in Yosemite because of recent modifications to kext security management that affects Trim support. [More about Trim Enabler for Mac](http://www.cindori.org/trim-enabler-and-yosemite/).

> About Trim in Yosemite In OS X 10.10 (Yosemite),
>
> Apple has introduced a new security requirement called kext signing. (A kext is
>   a kernel extension, or a driver, in Mac OS X)
>
> Kext signing basically works by checking if all the drivers in the
>   system are unaltered by a third party, or approved by Apple. If they
>   have been modified, Yosemite will no longer load the driver. This is a
>   means of enforcing security, but also a way for Apple to control what
>   hardware that third party developers can release OS X support for.
>
> Since Trim Enabler works by unlocking the Trim driver for 3rd party
>   SSD’s, this security setting prevents Trim Enabler to enable Trim on
>   Yosemite.
>
> To continue to use Trim Enabler and continue to get Trim for your
>   third party SSD, you first need to disable the kext signing security
>   setting.
>
> It is important to note that the kext-signing setting is global, if
>   you disable it you should be careful to only install system drivers
>   from sources that you trust.

Some drives work without Trim enabled: [ZDNet on issues with Trim in Yosemite](http://www.zdnet.com/article/os-x-yosemite-and-third-party-ssds-heres-what-you-need-to-know/).

Comment: [ZDNet on issues with Trim in Yosemite](http://www.zdnet.com/article/os-x-yosemite-and-third-party-ssds-heres-what-you-need-to-know/).

Answer (score 1):

**An error occurred was not able to extract essential.pkg**

I found a way to get this back on track (if you not having third party RAM) took me lots of time trial and error, my computer got so bad in the end it could not boot up even in safe made (left shift key during boot up.
Then when I in the only mode it was starting up by now (in CMD + R key start up mode) tried to install it was not recognized by Apple any more so they wouldn't let me DL the system again  (I have DL it 7 or 8 times by now, luckily Im on a 120 GB plan)
Was starting to panic quite badly by then...
But have no fears friend, there is a remedy for this!!!
Start up in Internet Recovery Mode, Opt + CMD + R key during start up, it takes a while but then a globe starts spinning on the screen and goes on and on and on so please be patient.
Then it reeboots itself and you get back to a screen looking identical to the CMD + R start up, after that it just sorted itself out, instal was a piece of p1ss and Yosemite 10.10.3 running sweet

Hope this helps for those with this problem, cheers

Answer (score 0):

I replaced HDD in my MBP(late 2010) with a OWC 250Gb SSD drive. After booting MBP from USB Bootloader (Yosemite), there is a customize button on the bottom left. Click "Customize" and uncheck Operating system scripts (0KB) [this is the trick I needed]. Leave Essential software (8 GB0 option checked. Continue install to SSD. Voila! mac OS X Yosemite Install completed Successfully. No more "there was an error extracting essentials.pkg" message. For verification , rebooted my MBP it still works. I even get prompted for Catalina Update .